# How to push files to sbin folder on the Android device?

Tags: android, root

I'm not able to turn on recovery mode, just the factory mode.

Communication between PC (Windows) and Android phone works fine over ADB, but the phone is not storing files after reboot.

Script in which I'm trying to transfer certain files ((sd)parted) to /sbin directory:

```
adb -d shell stop

adb -d shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount rootfs /"

adb -d shell su -c "chmod 0777 /sbin"

echo Copying files
adb push e2fsck /sbin/
adb push mke2fs /sbin/
adb push parted /sbin/
adb push resize2fs /sbin/
adb push sdparted /sbin/
adb push tune2fs /sbin/

echo Rebooting
adb reboot
```

Why files aren't stored on the device. What went wrong?

I need to repartition the file system, so that's the reason why I need these files.

```
adb root
```

... does not work, it get's stuck.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to. The rootfs in Android gets put into the boot image, which is compressed and expands into a ramdisk by the bootloader on bootup. This has the kernel, init, read-only properties, sbin, etc. If you remount the rootfs as root and write to these locations, your changes won't persist after a reboot. (ie they won't be written to the compressed boot.img)

You could get the AOSP or Cyanogenmod for your device if it is available, and rebuild the whole boot image with your files included, then flash that to your device. Here, you can also modify your partition table. I wouldn't recommend this, unless you really know what you are doing.